# How to store an ID to answers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Q&A app where users can ask questions and get answers. I am having some troubles with the answers part.

I am trying to store the question's ID inside the answers table but it always come back nil when I check it inside the console.

```
  def new
    #question scaffold
    if user_signed_in? 
      @question = current_user.questions.build
      respond_with(@question)
    else
      redirect_to new_user_session_path
    end
    #answer scafold
      @answer = Answer.create
      @question = Question.find(params[:id])
      @answer.question_id = @question
      @answer.save!
      redirect_to root_path
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    #create question
    @question = current_user.questions.build(question_params)
    @question.save

    #create answer
    @answer = Answer.create(answer_params)
    @question = Question.find(params[:id])
    @answer.question_id = @question
    @answer.save!
    redirect_to :back
  end
```

Comment: what is your association with question and answer table

Comment: the answers table can be looked at as comments if it makes it easier. I already set up the relation with the has_many and belongs_to. It works well and displays the answer in the right question when I manually add the `question_id` inside the console. What I am trying to do is store the question's ID inside the answers table without actually going to the console and doing it myself

Answer (score 0):

You have several issues with your code. First, you should add a database constraint to prevent answers being saved without a question id. Generate a migration that does this.

```
add_foreign_key :answers, :questions
```

Use a validation to ensure that an answer requires the `question_id` to be set.

```
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :question_id, presence: true
end
```

You should also use ActiveRecord relations to make building your models easier.

```
@answer = @question.answers.build(answer_params)
@answer.save
```

Which brings us to the issues with your code. It's unclear to me what `new` is doing here. Is it two actions? One action? If it's one action, you are setting the `@answer.question_id` to a blank value since `@question` was built, and not saved.

Also, make sure you are using `strong_parameters` and whitelisting attributes that the user can set in the form.

Comment: I just noticed that both of us actually live in the same country. Are you open for private sessions or any?

Comment: @Raymond Can do me a favour? Can you please update the code in your question to show each controller and only the relevant actions within that controller? I am Lebanese, but these days I live in São Paulo, Brazil. But I'd be happy to help in anyway I can.

Comment: is there a way to private message you?

Answer (score 0):

You just created the Question in the action so why you expect Question id to be sent to the action, check the following i changed #create answer part to use the created question:(am i miss something ?)

```
def create
 #create question
 @question = current_user.questions.build(question_params)
 @question.save

 #create answer
 @answer = Answer.create(answer_params)
 @answer.question = @question
 @answer.save!
 redirect_to :back
end
```